# Regex to extract text between specific charter

Tags: c#, regex

**I have below string as input**

" Mortgage ("Mortgage") in the amount of $500.00, dated July 1, 2018 herewith "

**and in output, I want as only**

$500.00

I tried with below regex but is' not working

```
Regex = new Regex(@"the amount of \$(.*)", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

SO can anyone please guide me what's wrong which I did?

With above regex, I already got the output as **500.00, dated July 1, 2019 herewith**.

But I only want $500.00 as output.

Comment: `\$(\d+)+(.\d+)` should work. Check this example: https://regex101.com/r/IaQark/1

Comment: @MarTin That pattern requires at least 3 characters and would also match for example `$1Q1`

Comment: @MarTin also your suggested one will match strings like `$500A123`

Comment: In the example `new Regex` is not assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?` and loop through all matches:

```
cstring value = "Mortgage (\"Mortgage\") in the amount of $500.00, dated July 1, 2018 herewith";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(value, @"\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str=@" Mortgage (""Mortgage"") in the amount of $500.00, dated July 1, 2019 herewith ";
Regex rg = new Regex(@"the amount of \$(.*), dated ", RegexOptions.Singleline);
//@"\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
var ans = rg.Match(str).Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(o => o.Value.Replace("\n", "").Trim());
```